# Can enough RF power melt an antenna?

Tags: power, rf, antenna

I've heard of someone getting RF burns by touching a high power antenna. If enough power is supplied to the antenna could it melt, or would anything else happen? If so, how much power would have to be supplied?

Comment: RF burns hurt, a lot. Trust me, I know ;o) Actually [RF  can be used for surgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrosurgery).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, of course.

There is a current in the antenna element and it has a finite resistance. Therefore, Ohm's law applies.

### How much?

How much power is required to melt an antenna is, like everything else in the universe, dependent on the situation.

- Ambient temperature
- Dimensions of the antenna
- Architecture of the antenna
- Material choices/properties
- Frequency of operation

Comment: Also, the skin effect likely applies, in that the current is constrained to the region near the perimeter.  Many antenna elements are hollow, rather than solid, since the missing interrior would contribute little in the way of conductivity (at RF) or strength in comparison to the weight/expense of a solid element.